# Shopatron - Immediate Order Processing - Do I need to sync up my products and customer data with Shopatron?

Tags: customer, api, products, xmlrpc

A client wants to use Shopatron for processing orders and transmitting these to several retailers etc. and Magento for controlling inventory, customer data and the general front-end. The complete checkout would also be in Magento.

So we would be using the Immediate Order Processing API to send order data to Shopatron (http://developer.shopatron.com/ImmediateOrderProcessing). Our question here is quite simple, but somehow not answered by the developer documentation.

Do we need to sync the catalog data/product data and customer accounts from Magento to Shopatron or is Shopatron able to handle new products and customers and create these on-the-fly during the order processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Immediate Order Processing API, catalog and product data do not need to be sync'd with Shopatron.  As orders enter our system, new products will just be added with the data that is passed to us.